# How to track tweets with links with the streaming api?

Tags: api, twitter, streaming

I'm currently using the streaming API to track tweets with a specific hashtag but is it possible to filter them even more to only include tweets with links? I tried adding "filter:links" like in the search api but it didn't return anything even though when I search "#myhashtag filter:links" in the twitter website it does return new tweets.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

[DataSift](http://datasift.com) allows this. You can search on the domain, URL, title or Retweet count of links, as well as searching the text content of Tweets for keywords or #hashtags.
Take a look at the [DataSift Documentation](http://dev.datasift.com) or [DataSift Tech Blog](http://dev.datasift.com/blog) for more info